# how to convert the excel below to json

Tags: json, excel, js-xlsx

I want to convert excel to json like below.I want to use js-xlsx,but i don't know how to implement it

```
{"OrderNo":"120555",
"Order Date":"20160218",
"Courier Bill NO":"120555",
"orderShipperName":"INLAY SHOES ",
"ConsigneeName":"LEE",
"part":[{"description":"USB","qty":"2","units":"PCM"},
      {"description":"IPONE","qty":"3","units":"PCM"}]}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like valid json to me

Comment: No, it is not. Just copy/paste to jsonformatter and you will see that "part" needs double quotes, one "]" is leaking...

Comment: {
    "OrderNo": "120555",
    "Order Date": "20160218",
    "Courier Bill NO": "120555",
    " orderShipperName": "INLAY SHOES ",
    "ConsigneeName": "LEE",
    "part": [
        {
            "description": "USB",
            "qty": "2",
            "units": "PCM"
        },
        {
            "description": "IPONE",
            "qty": "3",
            "units": "PCM"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: `jq` parses this as JSON. Where do you have a problem with it?

Comment: I don't know how to get .